# How do I read(open) an ASN.1 file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, pyopenssl

I want to get a certificates serial number using python:

````
der = open('/Users/me/MyApp/Payload/codesign0').read()```
cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, der
cert.get_serial_number()
````

Unfortunately it fails in the first line:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

How do I read an ASN.1 file format (DER) in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file as a text file, which means `read` tries to decode the data using UTF-8 in order to return a `str` object.

Instead, open it as a binary file, so that `read` simply returns a `bytes` object without trying to decode the data at all.

```
 der = open('...', 'rb').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this `Python-ASN1 encoder and decoder`. Works for Python 2.6+ and 3.3+. Short example on page:

https://pypi.org/project/asn1/

Make sure to install `pip install future` before `pip install asn1`

Answer (score 0):

PyOpenSSL is being deprecated, so might want to consider using the **cryptography** module instead

```
import cryptography
der = open('/path/tp/file', 'rb').read()
cert = cryptography.x509.load_der_x509_certificate(der)
cert.serial_number
```